# How to merge two dataset?

Tags: openrefine

I have multiple data tables (XLS) like this (e.g):

```
| People      |Company| ID  |
|-------------|-------|-----|
| John Smith  | SFD   |A1234|
| John Doe    | MMF   |A1235|
| Jane Doe    | EEF   |A1236|
| John Smith  | EEF   |A1237|
```

I want to create a single project for them. However It seems impossible to merge two projects, or import additional data to an existing project.

Comment: Hello Jack. When you create a project, you can import multiple files at once. If the column names are the same, OR will merge them. Same thing if you have an Excel workbook with many Sheets.

Comment: How can I add additional data to an existing project?

Comment: No way to add new rows once the project is created (but you can add new columns using a sort of VLOOKUP).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Ettore in the comment, once you created a project, you cannot append data. You will need to export your project and either

- append your data via a third party tool like a spreadsheet software
- create a new project by importing together your new file and previous export.